# Keras with TensorFlow backend not using GPU

Tags: docker, keras, tensorflow

I built the gpu version of the docker image https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker with keras version 2.0.0 and tensorflow version 0.12.1. I then ran the mnist tutorial https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py but realized that keras is not using GPU. Below is the output that I have

```
root@b79b8a57fb1f:~/sharedfolder# python test.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Downloading data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/12
2017-09-06 16:26:54.866833: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-06 16:26:54.866855: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-06 16:26:54.866863: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-06 16:26:54.866870: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-06 16:26:54.866876: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

Can anyone let me know if there are some settings that need to be made before keras uses GPU ? I am very new to all these so do let me know if I need to provide more information.

**I have installed the pre-requisites as mentioned on the [page](https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker#prerequisites)**

- Install Docker following the installation guide for your platform: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

I am able to launch the docker image

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /sharedfolder:/root/sharedfolder floydhub/dl-docker:cpu bash
```

- GPU Version Only: Install Nvidia drivers on your machine either from Nvidia directly or follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/floydhub/dl-setup#nvidia-drivers). Note that you don't have to install CUDA or cuDNN. These are included in the Docker container.

I am able to run the last step

```
cv@cv-P15SM:~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.66  Mon May  1 15:29:16 PDT 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

- GPU Version Only: Install nvidia-docker: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker, following the instructions here. This will install a replacement for the docker CLI. It takes care of setting up the Nvidia host driver environment inside the Docker containers and a few other things.

I am able to run the step [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)

```
# Test nvidia-smi
cv@cv-P15SM:~$ nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi

Thu Sep  7 00:33:06 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    310MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am also able to run the nvidia-docker command to launch a gpu supported image.

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following suggestions below

1. Check if you have completed step 9 of this tutorial ( https://github.com/ignaciorlando/skinner/wiki/Keras-and-TensorFlow-installation ). Note: Your file paths may be completely different inside that docker image, you'll have to locate them somehow.

I appended the suggested lines to my bashrc and have verified that the bashrc file is updated.

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0' >> ~/.bashrc
```

1. To import the following commands in my python file

   `import os
   os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"`

Both steps, done separately or together unfortunately did not solve the issue. Keras is still running with the CPU version of tensorflow as its backend. However, I might have found the possible issue. I checked the version of my tensorflow via the following commands and found two of them.

This is the CPU version

```
root@08b5fff06800:~# pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: tensorflow-tensorboard, six, protobuf, mock, numpy, backports.weakref, wheel
```

And this is the GPU version

```
root@08b5fff06800:~# pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 0.12.1
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: mock, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six
```

Interestingly, the output shows that keras is using tensorflow version 1.3.0 which is the CPU version and not 0.12.1, the GPU version

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

import tensorflow as tf
print('Tensorflow: ', tf.__version__)
```

Output

```
root@08b5fff06800:~/sharedfolder# python test.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Tensorflow:  1.3.0
```

I guess now I need to figure out how to have keras use the gpu version of tensorflow.

Comment: If you follow the Tensorflow installation guide ( https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ ) for your operating system it will tell you everything you need. You're most likely missing the CUDA and CUDAnn libraries.

Comment: @KDecker but it says on https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker that the gpu version comes with CUDA 8.0 and cuDNN v5

Comment: Ohh this is the Docker image. Sorry I glanced over that. I'm not sure what to tell you, other than, did you follow the image perquisites? (Installing the NVidia drivers and nvidia-docker)

Comment: Hi yes, I have followed the pre-requisites (updated my post)

Comment: Check if you have completed step 9 of this tutorial ( https://github.com/ignaciorlando/skinner/wiki/Keras-and-TensorFlow-installation ). Note: Your file paths may be completely different inside that docker image, you'll have to locate them somehow.

Comment: @KDecker ok ill look for the files to see if GPU support has been enabled tomorrow, then update this thread. Its 3am now. Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: Try to add the following code.import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""

Comment: @KDecker I have updated my post with your suggestions but they are both not working. I might have found the issue though i.e. keras is importing the CPU version of tensorflow, not the GPU version.

Comment: @kong: Can you please try "x_train /= 255." & "x_test /= 255." This solution looks very silly. But we are also having the same issue, our model not running on GPU. But after this change it works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is **never** a good idea to have both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` packages installed side by side (the one single time it happened to me accidentally, Keras was using the CPU version).

> I guess now I need to figure out how to have keras use the gpu version of tensorflow.

You should simply remove both packages from your system, and then re-install `tensorflow-gpu` [UPDATED after comment]:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Moreover, it is puzzling why you seem to use the `floydhub/dl-docker:cpu` container, while according to the instructions you should be using the `floydhub/dl-docker:gpu` one...

Comment: Wow you are most right. Although I found out that I had to uninstall both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu then re-install tensorflow-gpu. If I only uninstall tensorflow then somehow python does not detect the gpu version. Getting libraries to work can be very draining.

Comment: Now it works. I mean after uninstalling tensoflow-gpu as well. and than reinstalling tensorflow-gpu. Before it didn't work.

Comment: @khan hehe, good thing you woke me up to edit it by downvoting first - thanks ;)

Comment: @desertnaut :D Thank you for updating it.

Comment: Doesn't removing `tensorflow` (CPU version) make you to don't be able to use `tensorboard`?

Comment: @BtcSources Tensorboard is usable by both Tensorflow versions - CPU & GPU

Answer (score 6):

I had similar kind of issue - keras didn't use my GPU.  I had tensorflow-gpu installed according to instruction into conda, but after installation of keras it simply not listed GPU as available device. I've realized that installation of keras adds tensorflow package! So I had both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu packages. I've found that there is keras-gpu package available. After complete uninstallation of keras, tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu and installation of tensorflow-gpu, keras-gpu the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

In the future, you can try using virtual environments to separate tensorflow CPU and GPU, for example:

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

AND

```
conda create --name tensorflow-gpu python=3.5
activate tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:
Install tensorflow v2.2.0
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
Also remove tensorflow-gpu (if it's present)