# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

So I am new to machine learning and was trying out the TensorFlow Linear Model Tutorial given here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

I literally just downloaded their tutorial and tried to run it in my computer but I got the error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column'

I searched online and got to know that this can happen on older versions of tensorflow, but I am running the latest version: 1.3.0

So why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: On top of the answer by @Mingxing , check for possible presence of both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` in your `pip list`.

Comment: Well yeah, I have both `tensorflow (1.3.0)` and `tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0)` What to do now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771019/tensorflow-keras-do-not-use-all-available-resources/46772433#46772433 - although, since both are v1.3.0,  does not seem related to your reported issue

Comment: so like you suggested, I uninstalled both and then installed `tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0)` but it still didn't help. I am still getting that error

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow 1.3 should support feature_column well. You might accidentally used an old version. Try the following code to verify your version:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(dir(tf.feature_column))
```

Comment: I got `1.3.0` and `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_allowed_symbols', 'bucketized_column', 'categorical_column_with_hash_bucket', 'categorical_column_with_identity', 'categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file', 'categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list', 'crossed_column', 'embedding_column', 'indicator_column', 'input_layer', 'linear_model', 'make_parse_example_spec', 'numeric_column', 'weighted_categorical_column']`

Comment: If I write your code in Anaconda prompt, then it works fine and prints what I posted in the above comment. But if I copy the same code in a python script and try to run it, then I get that attribute error.

Comment: What is the output of print(tf.__version__) after run your python script?

Comment: I get `1.3.0` for `print(tf.__version__)`

Comment: I have 0.12.0. Is that the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

If you're importing Tensorflow in a project that uses Keras, import Keras modules first, then Tensorflow.  That solved the problem for me.

**Do this**: (notice the order)

```python
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import applications

import tensorflow as tf
```

**Do not do** this:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import applications
```

Answer (score 2):

**Upgrading your tensorflow might help.**

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error while running a session using the Tensorflow 2.0 beta. I used the following form for running a session:

```
import tensorflow as tf
constant = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(constant))
```

instead of:

```
import tensorflow as tf
constant = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
with tf.Session() as sess:
      print(sess.run(constant))
```

Also,

```
tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

is backward compatible. You might face a similar error when using other functions in Tensorflow 2.0 beta like print, get_variable, etc. Use a similar form as shown above in the example.