# How to install Keras with gpu support?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda, gpu

I installed Tensorflow for GPU using: `pip install tensorflow-gpu` 
But when I tried the same for **Keras** `pip install keras-gpu`, it pulled me an error: *could not find the version that satisfies the requirements*.

Comment: Please state the version of Python used. Also note, keras-gpu is a conda install, not  pip install.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is **not** any `keras-gpu` package [**UPDATE**: *now* there is, see other answer above]; Keras is a wrapper around some backends, including Tensorflow, and these backends may come in different versions, such as `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`. But this does not hold for Keras itself, which should be installed simply with

```
pip install keras
```

independently of whatever backend is used (see the [PyPi docs](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/)).

Additionally, and since you have tagged the question as `anaconda`, too, be informed that it is generally not advisable to mix your package managers (i.e `pip` with `conda`), and you may be better off installing Keras from the [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras) with

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

Finally, you may be also interested to know that recent versions of Tensorflow include Keras as a subpackage, so you can use it without any additional installation; see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras

For installing `tensorflow-gpu` from [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu), you should use

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

before installing Keras. Be sure you do it in a different virtual environment, or after having uninstalled other versions (i.e. `pip`-installed ones), as there have been [reported problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080634/keras-with-tensorflow-backend-not-using-gpu/46095279#46095279) otherwise.

Comment: so instead pip install tensorflow-gpu .. What can i use to install in a anaconda

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas see updated answer (it was a simple Google search, in any case...); and if the answer has been helpful, kindly accept it - thanks

Comment: Still.. **System information**

* **Windows 7**
* **pip install tensorflow-gpu**
* Python version: **3.6.6**
* Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: **pip**
* CUDA/cuDNN version: **CUDA 8.0 cuDNN 7.1**
* GPU model and memory: **Model : Quadro 4000 , Memory : 18GB**

Installed using pip install tensorflow-gpu (No error, perfectly installed)
While importing tensorflow , i got a error : **Failed to load native tensorflow .ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**

Comment: Your initial question was about `keras-gpu`, which has been addressed in the answer. If you have a **different** issue with a different package, you are very welcome to open a new question, after accepting this one.

Answer (score 31):

Adding to the answer below which is the correct answer in terms of recommending to use Anaconda package manager, but out of date in that **there is** now a *keras-gpu* package on [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/keras-gpu).

So once you have Anaconda installed, you simply need to create a new environment where you want to install keras-gpu and execute the command:

`conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu`

This will install Keras along with both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu libraries as the backend. (There is also no need to install separately the CUDA runtime and cudnn libraries as they are also included in the package - tested on Windows 10 and working).

Comment: In that case, `keras` is using `tensorflow` CPU version as backend and not using GPU at all. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Installing tensorflow-gpu first and then installing keras-gpu worked! https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498829/3337089

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above two answers, ensure your TensorFlow/Keras environment is using Python 3.6. Keras/TensorFlow doesn't work very well with Python 3.7, as of May 10, 2019.

I tried to use Keras/TensorFlow with Python 3.7 and I ended up having to reinstall Anaconda, since it sort of broke my Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

To install tensorflow-gpu with particular cuda version 9.0, use:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu cudatoolkit==9.0 -c anaconda
```

Similarly for `keras-gpu`

Comment: this can cause conflicts with other newer cuda packages like pycuda

Comment: You shouldn't be having a problem if those packages are in different conda environments