# I can't install keras on tensorflow environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using python 3.8 and I installed **Tensorflow-gpu** on it via **command prompt**. Now I am going to install **keras** on it, but I can't. I am using

```
conda activate tensorflow
conda install -c keras-gpu
```

but it fails.
I also tried from anaconda navigator. But whenever I try to add keras-gpu, it doesn't show anything. No packages come on pop-up window. When I try keras, it says that my python version is 3.8. Keras can't be installed. What can I do now? If there is a **offline** process to install keras on tensorflow environment, it will be helpful for me. So can you please help me?

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow on your virtual environment tensorflow ?

Comment: Yes, I have done

Comment: Kindly look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689096/how-to-install-keras-with-gpu-support