# Tensorflow not using the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` using `pip` (within Anaconda). Here is the verification:

`$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow-gpu (1.4.0)`

But whenever I run a model, it uses the CPU. Can someone please help.

Another command I tried:

`$ find . -name tensorflow
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow
./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow`

Is there a conflict?

Comment: why is there a "-1" next to the post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow not running on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829085/tensorflow-not-running-on-gpu)

Comment: Faced the similar issue. My situation was tensorflow-gpu was installed using conda, while pip installed tensorflow cpu version.  I re-installed tensorflow-gpu using pip fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using a Nvidia-gpu have you installed cuda and cudnn before installing Tensorflow with gpu support? check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux). Moreover use pip or pip3 to install tensorflow because Anaconda will not have the latest version of tensorflow.

also try running the following in a python or a ipython shell

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

You will get a sample output and if you see your GPU device in the message then tensorflow is using your gpu

Comment: I tried the same, and I can see my gpu in the list. I have an MSI. using my Dragon centre, which shows the stats and metrics of my hardware in function,  I can see that my GPU is not being used, but rather, all of my RAM is being used. Is it something that cannot be picked by the metrics?

Also, when I am running my games, I can see that the GPU is being used.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Do you have a nvidia GPU or a AMD?