# My tensorflow doesn't detect my gpu and use my cpu (machine learning)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cpu-usage

I try to train a machine learning model with my rtx380 10g and I use ubuntu 20.4 on my computer.

When i lunch my application, it says me :

```
2021-07-02 10:29:53.581609: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:114] CPU Frequency: 2496000000 Hz
```

after that, i tried to print len(my phisical_devices('Gpu')) but it gives me "0".

I installed Conda, but i'm not sure it's working. (Same for Cudnn)

To be honest, i'm quite lost now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, did you install CUDA Toolkit, is it the right version based on your GPU?

Also did you do

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Try this thread: [Tensorflow not running on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829085/tensorflow-not-running-on-gpu)

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a compatibility issue. Make sure your TF version is compatible with the Python, Cuda & Cudnn versions that are installed on ur PC and make sure that Microsoft Visual Studio is installed.

I'm currently using TF2.4, Python 3.8, Cuda 11.0 and Cudnn 8.0. Give this combination a try and see if it works.